# Can't get the user's session on the server side using Supabase

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-js

I'm reading these Supabase authentication tutorials (for example this one) where they feature some code on Next.js' API routes like this:

```
(pages/api/getUser.js) 

export default async function getUser(req, res) {
    const user = await supabase.auth.user();
    return res.status(200).json({ user: user });
}
```

It's not the only tutorial I see that they perform a user-related function from a backend (check out this other one if you're curious) and also it's from the v1 Supabase client version (I'm using v2).
When I try and do something like that (pretty much the same just up-to-date to Supabase client v2) for example:

```
(pages/api/getUser.js) 

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse ) {

const user = await supabase.auth.getSession();

 if (!user) {
     return res.status(401).json({ message: "User not authenticated" });
    }

console.log("serverGetUser", user); 
return res.status(200).json({ user }); 
}
```

It returns: `{ data: { session: null }, error: null }`

When I try to do that same function on the client side (inside a useEffect) is returns everything correctly.

My first thought is, how can the server bring if the user is connected? Isn't that literally impossible and only for the browser to know? But at the same time I see all these tutorials doing it and wondering if I'm just doing/thinking this very wrong.

That's what confuses me. Any input is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To do both server-side and client-side auth, you should use the `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs` as this handles all the relevant pieces to get this working. Our quick start tutorial shows how to get his working https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs

Comment: @AndrewSmith Yes, this documentation was what saved me. Thanks